# stdout collisions on node

Tags: node.js, stream, stdout, webstorm, winston

If multiple processes are simultaneously writing to stdout then there is nothing to stop the streams from interleaving.  This is what I mean by a collision. 
[image]
According to the comments in the [node source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_writable.js#L71), it should be possible to avoid collisions in `process.stdout`.  I tried this and it helps but I still get collisions.   Without the `writing` flag, I get collisions every time, with the flag it drops to about 40%.  Still very significant.

```
page.on('onConsoleMessage', function log(message) {
  var writing = process.stdout._writableState.writing
    || process.stdout._writableState.bufferProcessing
    || process.stdout.bufferSize ;
  if(writing)
    process.nextTick(message => log(message));
  else
    process.stdout.write('-> ' + message + '\n')
});
```

What is the best way to avoid collisions on `process.stdout`?

The above routine is competing with [Winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) for `stdout`.

node v5.12.0
Windows 10

This problem only happens when using the Run console in webstorm, the output is not mixed up when running node in powershell or from cmd.  I raised a [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23329) for this at jetbrains.

Comment: Can you define what a collision is?

Comment: @robertklep, have you seen [The Fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fly_(1958_film))?

Comment: Haha I get the idea ;D So you are getting character-interleaving between different log lines? Or line-interleaving, where you log multiple lines with one logger and they get interleaved by the other logger?

Comment: @robertklep Yep, that's right.  I also tried using `console.log` but got the same result: collisions about 40% of the time.  Actually, it's not character level interleaving, the interrupting message is printed complete, then the interrupted on resumes.

Comment: If you log multiple lines with each logger, I don't think there's anything you can do to prevent _line_ interleaving (because logging a single line usually is an isolated operation: `logger.log('line1'); logger.log('line 2')`, ...). However, it's strange that one logger would be able to "break" lines of the other logger, since they both write to the same stream semi-atomically (unless `write` is called multiple times for a single log line, _or_ unless one logger is writing to `stdout` and the other to `stderr`).

Comment: AHHH, yes! That must be it.  I am now getting clean output by logging to stderr.  I think you nailed it. If you have time to post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple writers *to the same stream*, I don't think that you'll get interleaving. Even if a single writer is logging multiple lines in succession, those lines will be buffered (if there is buffering going on) in the correct order, and when another writer is logging its lines, they will be appended to the buffer, behind the previously logged lines.

Interleaving *can* occur when you have writers writing to a different stream, like one writing to `stdout` and the other to `stderr`. At some point, when the output buffer of one stream fills up, it gets flushed to the console, regardless of any other streams that may also be writing to console.